# SignalR.Owin vs. SignalR.SelfHost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, self-hosting

I want to use SignalR selfhosted with Owin.

What are the differences between these two packages:

[Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR OWIN](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin/)

and

[Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR Self Host](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost/)

When to use one or other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main difference is, that `Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR OWIN` is an older package, because it depends on `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core (>= 1.2.2)`. And `Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR Self Host` depends on `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core (>= 2.2.0)`. That is why I will use the `Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR Self Host` package.

Answer (score 10):

`Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR Self Host` still uses OWIN to startup. The only difference is that the Self Hosted SignalR server doesn't need to be nested in an ASP.NET web application hosted in IIS. It can be a simple console application.

[See MSDN for more info:](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

Reasons for not hosting in IIS include:

- Environments where IIS is not available or desirable, such as an existing server farm without IIS.
- The performance overhead of IIS needs to be avoided.
- SignalR functionality is to be added to an exising application that runs in a Windows Service, Azure worker role, or other process.

Comment: I know the reasons for not hosting in IIS. That's why I want to self host SignalR. But both linked packages are for self host. I don't understand the differences of these two. Both are using OWIN.

Comment: It is because the Self Host dll includes `HttpListener` which is needed to listen on port 80, and since that's the job of IIS in the first place, this class is needed for a connection to be made with SignalR because you are not using IIS.

Comment: Microsoft has segmented the SignalR into multiple NuGet packages so that you can use the correct package according to your needs, that way you reduce unnecessary dependencies